# Flask 1.1.x - Basic Routing using templates issue

Tags: python, flask

So I'm following along with the tutorial on Flask from LinkedIn: "Full Stack Web Development with Flask
". And I ran into this issue on the topic of routing using templates. I don't know what is casuing the issue since I'm very new to Flask and I haven't seen anything about it on the documentation. What I think it is is that I must've coded something that Flask cannot run, syntax-wise,since it's Flask's own files that are producing the issues from the compiler. I am sure that the issue is coming from the routing because the error happens after I run "flask run" on the command line and then reload the page.

Error messages:

```
   File
 "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 2446, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 1820, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",
 line 39, in reraise
     raise value   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 1935, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask\enrollment\application\routes.py", line
 7, in index
     return render_template('index.html')   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
 line 137, in render_template
     return _render(   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
 line 120, in _render
     rv = template.render(context)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py",
 line 76, in render
     return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
 line 1008, in render
     return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
 line 780, in handle_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py",
 line 37, in reraise
     raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask\enrollment\application\templates\index.html",
 line 16, in 
     {% include "includes/nav.html" %}   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
 line 1005, in render
     return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))   File
 "C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask\enrollment\application\templates\index.html",
 line 14, in root
        File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\flask\enrollment\application\templates\includes\nav.html",
 line 13, in root   File
 "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py",
 line 262, in call
     return __obj(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py",
 line 370, in url_for
     return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)   File
 "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
 line 2215, in handle_url_build_error
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",
 line 39, in reraise
     raise value   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py",
 line 357, in url_for
     rv = url_adapter.build(   File "c:\users\user\desktop\flask\enrollment\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py",
 line 2020, in build
     raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self) werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint
 'courses'. Did you mean 'index' instead?
 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2019 09:42:23] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

routes.py

```
from application import app
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UTA - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid text-center top-container">
    <img src="static/images/uta-logo-200.png">
</div>
<div class="container">

    {% include "includes/nav.html" %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>Welcome to Universal Tech Academy.</h1>

            {% if login %}
            <h3>Let's get started.</h3>
            {% else %}
            <p>Already registered? <a href="{{url_for('login') }}">Login</a></p>
            {% endif %}

            </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% include "includes/footer.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not build url for endpoint 'courses'. Did you mean 'index'
>   instead? 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2019 09:42:23] "GET /index HTTP/1.1"
>   500 -

werkzeug is trying to build the routing endpoint for "courses", but doesn't find any routable endpoint for it.

you need to construct another route in your flask code for it to work, like you did with index:

```py
@app.route('/courses')
def courses():
    return render_template('courses.html')
```

Comment: np, glad to help :)